# Parsing html data from a site which uses javascript to populate

Tags: php, parsing, jquery

I know we can parse remote site's html by using **simple_HTML_Dom** class.It is pretty easy!.

What i would like to know is that i am looking to parse a data of remote site's html'  whose  get  populated by some JS/jquery/AJAX.How one can get that data? What is the trick?

ThankYou in Advance!

Comment: soory!! i meant to say there is a select tag whose options get populated by JS/Jquery/AJAX...how to do it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Firefox plugin using XUL/JS and parse the populated DOM if you need to.